# How to remove random lines from a text file with PHP

Tags: php, random, lines

Say I have a text file with a bunch of lines (the real text file has a LOT more):

```
Testing
Test
Another line
Blah
ABCDEFG
```

How can I remove a random amount of lines from this file with PHP? So that means, I can specify how many lines I want to remove randomly.

From what I know so far, I believe I would have to put the lines in an array, and randomly remove them from there. However, I do not know how to do that. I THINK I might need to use `shuffle()`, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: Do the lines need to go back into the file in the same order as they were in originally?

Comment: @webnoob Nope, actually, I'd prefer the lines to be in a random order.

Comment: read the file with `file()`, `shuffle()` the array, `array_shift()` a few lines off the front of the array, `implode()` it back to a string and `file_put_contents()` back to the file.

Comment: Just read the line-count (or `\n`) and randomize 5 times (check for uniqueness to avoid conflicts) and rebuild the string and let the loop iteration skip the randomized line numbers. Afterwards write the whole shebang back to the file.

Comment: Oh, I guess `file_put_contents()` accepts an array so you skip the `implode()` step in my description.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I apologize, I'll keep that in mind for the next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help in the comments, it seems like I solved my problem!

```
<?php
$items = file_get_contents("items.txt");
$items = explode("\n", $items);
shuffle($items);
$x = 1;
while ($x <= 800) {
    array_shift($items);
    $x++;
}
print_r($items);
?>
```

Like the comments stated, I loaded the file, exploded it by each new line, used `shuffle()` on the items, and ran a while loop using `array_shift()` to remove the random lines.